# Quartz custom (non-standard) jobstore

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have our own (non-standard,) custom data store. How can I have my Quartz scheduler to persist and retrieve the schedule data from the custom data store?

Comment: One possible way, that might work is to extend `JobStore` , that takes care of all the storage and retrieval. Yet to implement and test and it.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this and its work for me:

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  {
    var props = new NameValueCollection
    {
      {"quartz.jobStore.type", "<<full class name>>, <<assembly name>>"}
    };

    var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
    var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

    await scheduler.Start();
 }
}
```

also after that you can have exception about serialization so add

```
{"quartz.serializer.type", "binary"}
```

to NameValueCollection